# Search NVARCHAR(MAX) string in other string

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to find the index of a string in other string. I try to use `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX` but nothing worked because the search string is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and these functions are limited to 8000 chars only.

I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 13
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Are there any alternatives?

The goal is to replace the find string with other, but `REPLACE` is not working with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` either. That's why I am trying to use `.WRITE` clause but need to calculate the offset.

This is sample code. Basically, I am trying to replace the source of `img` HTML tags from `BASE64` to relative url.

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Content] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @defaultStartScreenOld nvarchar(max) = N'a NVARCHAR(MAX) big image in BASE64 format';
DECLARE @defaultStartScreenNew nvarchar(2000) = N'images/surveo/presetImages/Thumb_PointerStart.jpg';

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Content])
SELECT CONCAT('<RUSLAN src="', @defaultStartScreenOld, '"/>')

SELECT [Content]
FROM @DataSource

UPDATE @DataSource
--SET [Content].WRITE(@defaultStartScreenNew, 10, LEN(@defaultStartScreenNew))
SET [Content] = REPLACE([Content], @defaultStartScreenOld, @defaultStartScreenNew)

SELECT [Content]
FROM @DataSource
```

Comment: You should show the table structure and the code that leads to that error. I suspect something is not right (and I don't think you should be using methods like `.WRITE`).

Comment: Try this in your code: `UPDATE @foo SET x = REPLACE(x, REPLICATE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), N'x'),80001) , N'flarb');
`

Comment: So you're replacing a > 4000 character portion of an existing NVARCHAR(MAX) column with another portion that is > 4000 characters? Why wouldn't you just write the whole value? PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE clarify your question with the code and ***exactly*** what you are trying to do. I've already wasted time because your problem isn't actually the one you've described.

Comment: I have added a sample code. Just not been able to add the real base64 string as it is very large, but basically this is the idea.

Comment: I have a table with column that holds HTML content. I am not able to do the replace by hand as there are many records, and I am not able to write the whole value as the content is different.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting writing by hand. But you could certainly write a program pretty quickly that would read each value, do the replace, and then update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17947/discussion-between-gotqn-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: You need to run this on hundreds of instances? Sounds like a better use case for PowerShell than T-SQL, to be honest.

Comment: Sounds like a good time for me to learn something new (PowerShell as you said or C# to write CLR procedure) - I hate when I don't have the knowledge to do something.

Comment: I wouldn't use a CLR procedure. You're going to run into the same kinds of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that:

- `REPLACE`, `PATINDEX`, `CHARINDEX` and even `LIKE` have not been updated to fully and properly deal with LOB/MAX types; and,
- you need to repeat this process across hundreds of databases and against multiple instances

I would strongly recommend you look at doing this outside of SQL Server, probably in PowerShell or C# (not CLR inside SQL Server, which will be prone to similar data type limitations and restrictions). You can write a simple C# command line program that pulls in each row, performs the replace inline, and then updates the row wholesale. Then you can point the C# app at each instance/database combination. PowerShell may have some limitations with handling huge chunks of data like this, but I recommend looking into that as well simply due to the automation factor (you can simply feed it a text file of instance/database names and it will churn through all of them in one shot). Even if you could trust the CLR approach to do this correctly, I think the debugging effort will be higher, and you'll also have to deploy the assemblies everywhere (vs. a single app or script that can just be pointed at each instance in turn).

I'm not sure I'm the one you want giving specific guidance on the code you would write using either of these approaches, I just want to steer you away from trying to solve this in T-SQL, since the deck is kind of stacked against you there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on SQL Server 2014 and CHARINDEX seems to work ok on NVARCHAR(MAX).

```
DECLARE @TEST1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TEST2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @LOOP INT;

SET @TEST2 = '12345678';
SET @TEST1 = 'TEST';
SET @LOOP = 1;
WHILE @LOOP < 24
BEGIN
    SET @TEST2 = @TEST2 + @TEST2;
    SET @LOOP = @LOOP + 1;
END
SET @TEST2 = @TEST2 + @TEST1;
SELECT CHARINDEX(@TEST1,@TEST2) AS Search,LEN(@TEST2) AS Length,@@VERSION as SQLVersion;
```

[image: SQL Output]